# Need to collect info from Approver during approval workflow step

Tags: 2010, workflow, sharepoint-enterprise

Within a custom workflow in SP2010, I have an approval step.  When an approver brings up their screen to approve or reject, If they select "approve", I need to be able to collect another piece of information from them (a selection of 2 choices) at the same time.  I don't see a way to do this OOTB.

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a custom task form field and make it available to your task form. Check [Creating Custom Workflow Task Approval Forms with SharePoint Designer 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/edhild/archive/2011/06/01/creating-custom-workflow-task-approval-forms-with-sharepoint-designer-2010.aspx)

After you get that information, the value of that field can be accessed from "When Task Completes..." step of your approval task process. Not sure how you want to use it but you can store them in a workflow variable and use it in your workflow logic or you can update item (on which approval workflow is running) field with the value selected by the approver. Check following article for more information:

[Updating List Item with Task Form Custom Field in SharePoint Approval 2010 Workflow](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kishore/archive/2012/01/15/updating-list-item-with-task-form-custom-field-in-sharepoint-approval-2010-workflow.aspx)

Also, [Use the task process editor for approval workflows](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/use-the-task-process-editor-for-approval-workflows-HA101863538.aspx) contains general information on working with task process (approval task process in your case).